# Compressing sequence of unique sorted numbers

Tags: algorithm, compression

I a project I am working on, I have a sequence of numbers (around 2 billion). Each number is 4 bytes and unique. The numbers are sorted. My goal is to read them into the RAM ASAP in uncompressed format. It don't care about HDD space.

If I store them uncompressed, I need 2 billion*4 bytes = 8GB. This will take around 100 seconds to read. I can store the data as a sequence of bits and this will require 2 billion/8 = 250MB. This will take around 3 seconds to read.

I need to read and uncompress them in something like 0.1-0.5 seconds (if possible) using a normal HDD. I don't care how long it will take to compress the data but I really care how long it takes to decompress them and I need that to be done in a few milliseconds.

The randomness of the numbers is not known.

**The Question is**: What kind of compression algorithm can compress the numbers to around 20-30MB with a decompression time of 100-200 milliseconds using an i3-i5 CPU?

**EDIT**: The maximum number in sequence will be 2 billion. That's why I can store it on a bit array with a size of 250MB. The size of the sequence is not always 2 billion. It can contain from 1 to 2.000.000.000 numbers.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the statistics of the numbers the answers you're going to get are just going to be random guesses of people telling you to try this library or that one. The numbers are unique so you likely can't do much with them directly. You'll have to find some redundancy in the data first. For example, have you analyzed the statistics of the difference of sequential numbers to perhaps try a differential encoder on those differences?

Comment: @dpmcmlxxvi: For a word I am storing the the numbers of sentances that the word appears.

Comment: How are you going from 8GB to 250MB? How is the encoding different between 4 byte numbers (ints, presumably?) and "sequence of bits"?

Comment: @ mhum: I don't understand what do you mean here... Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: @AlgoCoder: In your question, you say that if you store the data as a sequence of bits, you will require 250MB. I'm not sure what you meant by "store the data as a sequence of bits".

Comment: @mhum: Instead of strong 0, 1, 4, 5, 7. I store: 11001101. I store 1 if the item at pos x exists and 0 if it doesn't.

Comment: @AlgoCoder: Ok, I see. What happens if you compress that bit string with some standard compression algorithm (e.g.: gzip)?

Comment: Have you tried a [run length encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) on your sequence of bits?

Comment: @mhum: I am designing the application and haven't started coding yet. I don't know that answer.

Comment: @ dpmcmlxxvi: No, I don't have that sequence of bit ready to test algorithms there.

Comment: If you have 2 billion unique numbers, all representable in 4 bytes (32 bits), that's about half the total possible numbers. (If they are all non-negative, that's nearly all of them.) Representing the set of numbers as a bit set is probably going to be the best you can do and being as dense as it sounds like it is, chances are very good that this will compress quite a bit using standard compression algorithms.

Comment: There's approximately 4^(2^31) different subsets of 2 billion 32 bit numbers (2n choose n ~= 4^n, and 2^31 ~= 2 billion), so unless you know something about their distribution you're going to need 2^32 bits to represent the set. That's 512MB and achievable by a bit set, and you can't do better in general.

Comment: Your calculation of 250MB is wrong because you're only counting 1 bits. Your bitset will include approximately 2 billion one bits but also approximately 2 billion zero bits, so the total size is 4 billion bytes or 500MB.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: Updated the question to make it clear why the bit array will take 250MB and not 500MB.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to store it as a sequence of bits would work as well as could be expected, but it would take 512 MiB to have a bit for every four-byte integer, not 250 MB.

A delta-coding scheme would work better for a less-dense set, but not this one (as described in the original question, which was a random choice of half of the possible 32-bit integers).  Here the delta 1 would occur about half the time, the delta 2 would occur a quarter of the time, and so on.  That would result in 2<sup>30</sup> + 2x2<sup>29</sup> + 3x2<sup>28</sup> + ... = 2<sup>32</sup> bits.  The same as the bit vector approach.

The optimal compression scheme would take the log base 2 of 2<sup>32</sup> choose 2<sup>31</sup> bits.  That also turns out to be 2<sup>32</sup> bits.  (Actually, 2<sup>32</sup>-16 bits, so it would be possible to save a whopping 16 bits out of four billion.)

So the bit vector is as good as it gets.

The updated question is entirely different.  Now the question has a wide range of a set of from one to all of the 31-bit integers, and asks how to compress that to 20 MiB to 30 MiB.

Those compressed sizes put a constraint on the size of the set.  Given the size of the set, one can simply count the number of possible subsets of the 31-bit integers of that size, let's call it *n*.  That count of possible subsets is 2<sup>31</sup> choose *n*.  ["choose" is the binomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html).  The logarithm base 2 of that number of possible subsets is the theoretical minimum of the compressed size of a particular subset in bits, assuming that all such subsets are equally likely.

So now we can compute the largest possible size that can compress to 20 MiB to 30 MiB.  That turns out to be 21 to 34 million.  You can also compress subsets of size 2<sup>31</sup> minus 21 to 34 million, since you can think of those as being identified by the values that are missing as opposed to the values that are there.  Anything in between will take more than 30 MiB to represent in a theoretically optimum compression scheme.  The updated question asks for the full range of possible subsets, the vast majority of which are between 34 million and 2.1 billion.

So, bottom line, it *is not possible* to compress the described sequences anywhere near as much as specified in the updated question.

Comment: That's a lot for the help. I don't exactly understand your answer but it seems correct. Given the edit in the question, do you have anything new to add?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible approaches:

1. The asker proposes storing the sequence of numbers as a bit string. E.g.: if the number *i* is in the sequence, then the *i*<sup>th</sup> bit of the bit string is set to one, otherwise it's zero. The natural first thing to try is to apply standard compression algorithms to this bit string and see what happens.
2. From the phrasing of the question, it seems that we can treat the numbers in the sequence as 4-byte ints. So, the sequence to be stored represents around 2*10<sup>9</sup> out of a possible 2<sup>32</sup> ints. Which means that the average difference between any two successive numbers can't be more than ~2.147 = 2<sup>32</sup> / (2*10<sup>9</sup>). So, maybe computing the sequence of differences and try compressing that. Since I would expect that a large fraction of the successive differences are going to be 1's and 2's, I suspect that this sequence might be very compressible.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.